# How to refresh MySQL version information?

Tags: mysql, php, zend-server

I'm using Zend Server on my local machine, recently I noticed some application incompatibility with version of MySQL.

While calling `mysql_get_client_info()` it would return `mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $` which is slightly incorrect format of MySQL version, for that reason `version_compare()` would not be able to parse it.

I decided to upgrade my server environment, during upgrade latest version of MySQL was downloaded and installed (5.1.36). Everything was installed correctly and confirmed in install log. However php still recognise it as `mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $`

Is it possible to refresh MySQL version without clean install of Zend Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_get_client_info() get MySQL client info, mysql_get_server_info() get MySQL server info. You install new MySQL server, and mysql_get_server_info() must change. To change mysql_get_client_info, update Zend Server or MySQL PHP modules.

Comment: I have updated them but mysql_get_client_info() is still the same, mysql_get_server_info() return '5.1.50-community' which is parsed correctly however on remote server it return false. Any other suggestions?

Comment: So mysql_get_client_info result are gathered from MySQL server or it is information of php extension? I'm quite confused now.

Comment: php extension version

Comment: so in order to update it I have to reinstall Zend Server?

Comment: yes, if new version Zend Server have new version php mysql extension